# CHANGEDOCUMENT_READ_HEADERS Why can't I read the creator of an entry?

Tags: abap

I started using CHANGEDOCUMENT_READ_HEADERS today and I need to find the creator of an entry. I've noticed that when there are no changes after the creation there will occur an error.

So if you just created an entry and try to get its changes via CHANGEDOCUMENT_READ_HEADERS, you'll get the NO_POSITION_FOUND exception. Apperantly, the creation of an entry, although it is visible in the changelog, does not count as a change.

Does anybody know a FM which allows me to find the creator of an entry?

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: Use CHANGEDOCUMENT_READ_HEADERS. Could you edit your question so that the question becomes "why doesn't it work", and please elaborate so that the question gets [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Yes I have already tried and I get an error when the entry hasn't had any changes yet. Apperantly the creation of an entry does not count as a change.

Comment: Refer the same question [here](https://answers.sap.com/questions/12685695/changedocument-read-headers-creator-of-entry.html), there might be some answers in the future.

Answer (score -1):

The CHANGEDOCUMENT_READ_HEADERS function module searches the change documents on the table CDHDR and CDPOS, if no changes were made on the document (Purchase order, FI document, etc.) no change document will be created.

To get the creator of an entry, you will need to get it directly from the table that stores the information or BAPI for that document.

For exemple: 
The purchase order creator can be found on the table EKKO (Purchasing Document Header) field ERNAM (Created by).

Comment: Thank you first of all. But how do I know which table contains the creator which I need? Can I find a list somewhere or how do I know in which table to search?

Comment: Usually the information can be found on the master table of the document you are looking for. I try searching on google the tables that are behind the document, sometimes on the transaction by pressing F1 on a field and going to the technical information you can give you some clue of the database table, another option is to use the SQL Trace (transaction: ST05). On the transaction SE11 you can push the matchcode button on the database option and search the table by description.